# Django mail attachment is blank

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to send a mail with an attachment using Django, the attached file is sent to the server from a user submitted form. My code is shown below

```
 form = RequestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
 if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.info(request, '')
        subject = ''
        message = ""
        attachment = request.FILES['attachment']
        mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, '', [''])
        mail.attach(filename=attachment.name, mimetype=attachment.content_type, content=attachment.read())
        mail.send()
```

I am receiving the mail, but the attachment in the mail is blank, i.e it doesn't contain any content. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I placed the form.save() at the bottom i.e after sending the mail and the issue resolved. This is because, once we use form.save() the attachment gets stored in its path and we need to open it before we read it.

```
form = RequestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
        messages.info(request, '')
        subject = ''
        message = ""
        attachment = request.FILES['attachment']
        mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, '', [''])
        mail.attach(filename=attachment.name, mimetype=attachment.content_type, content=attachment.read())
        mail.send()
        form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use attach_file instead of attach. attach_file allows you to pass a path, whereas you need to pass the actual data with attach. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects).

Also, test that your attachment is actually getting uploaded, that you specified the right enctype on your form, etc. For example:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/whatever/" method="post">
```